# QGIS Linux: qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found

Tags: python, linux

I would like to run code in Linux without GUI. I'm getting some error. How should i solve that?

```
>>> qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms" ...
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqeglfs.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqeglfs.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "eglfs"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QEglFSIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 330752
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("eglfs")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqlinuxfb.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqlinuxfb.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "linuxfb"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QLinuxFbIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 330752
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("linuxfb")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqminimal.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqminimal.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "minimal"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QMinimalIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 330752
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("minimal")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqminimalegl.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqminimalegl.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "minimalegl"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QMinimalEglIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 330752
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("minimalegl")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqoffscreen.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqoffscreen.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "offscreen"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QOffscreenIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 330752
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("offscreen")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqvnc.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqvnc.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "vnc"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QVncIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 330752
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("vnc")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "xcb"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QXcbIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 330752
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("xcb")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/usr/bin/platforms" ...
loaded library "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so"
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, xcb.

Aborted (core dumped)
gis@gis:~$ ^C
gis@gis:~$ sudo apt install xcb
[sudo] password for gis:
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for gis:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  clang clang-tidy clang-tidy-10 clang-tools-10 libclang1-8 libkf5syntaxhighlighting-data libkf5syntaxhighlighting5 libllvm8 libqbscore1.13 libqt5quicktest5 libqt5script5
  libqt5xmlpatterns5 qbs-common qml-module-qtgraphicaleffects qml-module-qtqml-models2 qml-module-qtquick-controls qml-module-qtquick-layouts qml-module-qtquick-window2
  qml-module-qtquick2 qtcreator-data qtcreator-doc
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  xcb
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 21.4 kB of archives.
After this operation, 65.5 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 xcb amd64 2.4-5 [21.4 kB]
Fetched 21.4 kB in 0s (187 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package xcb.
(Reading database ... 163559 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../archives/xcb_2.4-5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking xcb (2.4-5) ...
Setting up xcb (2.4-5) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
gis@gis:~$ screen -r
    "version": 330752
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("offscreen")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqvnc.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqvnc.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "vnc"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QVncIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 330752
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("vnc")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "xcb"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QXcbIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 330752
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("xcb")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/usr/bin/platforms" ...
loaded library "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so"
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, xcb.

Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: what about: https://forum.qt.io/topic/93247/qt-qpa-plugin-could-not-load-the-qt-platform-plugin-xcb-in-even-though-it-was-found/, https://github.com/therecipe/qt/issues/775, https://forum.qt.io/topic/115064/qt-qpa-xcb-could-not-connect-to-display/

Comment: didn't work for me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Solution:

```py
os.environ["QT_QPA_PLATFORM"] = "offscreen"
```

Comment: Leaving this here for future reference: this also applys when using `qgis_process` via ssh. In that case one would use `export QT_QPA_PLATFORM=offscreen` followed by the desired `qgis_process`